How can I prevent my website from loading fonts from my system?
How can I prevent my website from loading a font that I have installed on the system instead of the one defined to be imported?
Example, if I define:
body{
   font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

(My website shows this font although I have NOT imported it yet)
My website shows this font although I have NOT imported it yet.

Depending on your browser you may tweak your config to omit local fonts. See this post.  Otherwise just make sure your import or @font-face rules are correct and don't include any local() references
